# SQL Oracle 10g List all database tables and the columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got an Oracle 10g database with a few hundred tables and I want to create a list of the table name, the columns it has and the comments for those columns. A normal table look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMiq9.jpg

I want a list of the column_name and the comments from each table. I tried getting this from the metadata using:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, comments
  FROM user_tab_columns ;
```

But it errors out since I'm mixing metadata and not. I'm confused on how to get what I want.

Thanks

Comment: `user_tab_columns` doesn't have the comments column, you need to join it with `user_col_comments`. To know how, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a list of the column_name and the comments from each table.

Query `USER_COL_COMMENTS` and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, to select `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME` and `COMMENTS`.

Make a `JOIN` on `OWNER`, `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tc.table_name,
       tc.column_name,
       cc.comments
from  user_tab_columns  tc 
join  user_col_comments cc  
     on  cc.column_name = tc.column_name
     and cc.table_name  = tc.table_name
```